# Component not updating according to pattern card

Tags: experience-analytics, personalization

This is my first time I am using the personalization using persona. My problem is that in the experience analytics I can see that my page visits resembles the "Batman Pattern Card" as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

I have applied the rule as like following in the screenshot below:
[image]

Now the question is that reports are showing that visits matches the Batman pattern but it is not hiding the component on the page (according to rule) as applied on the home page item.

I have confirmed that I have applied correct profile's rule on the item.

Please confirm if I am missing something

Comment: Is the HTML caching turned on that rendering item?

Comment: Instead of using the rule you specified, try to use `where the current contact matches the specific pattern card in the specific profile`. This will be applied to all contacts who are in the Batman Pattern Card with profile Cartoon Liker

Comment: No @TamásTárnok cache is not enabled for that

Comment: Any update on this @PrashantTomar?

Comment: the rule you are using will check if the pattern `Batman Pattern` has been assigned to the user during the current visit. Try to assign the boost the pattern of the user on the current visit and then test your rule.

Comment: Can you check this setting in your instance. You cannot personalize on a visit persona until you have visited X number of pages 1st, that have profile scores. <setting name="Analytics.Patterns.MinimalProfileScoreCount" value="3" />

Comment: @HishaamNamooya answer works for me. Thanks

Comment: @PrashantTomar can you mark the answer below. I converted the comment to an answer to help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comment to answer

Instead of using the rule you specified in the question, use the condition

```
where the current contact matches the specific pattern card in the specific profile.
```

This will be applied to all contacts who are in the **Batman Pattern** Card with profile **Cartoon Liker**

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, Please double check below points..

1. Batman page should have assigned the Cartoon Liker Profile. Please find below screen for your reference.
2. For example, your want to hide some component on Home page based on user journey. If user has visited Batman page then on home page some component should be hidden as user should have assigned the Cartoon Liker Profile.
3. Make sure everything is published.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @NSP for reply. the profile card is already there on page there data is being tracked in the experience profile. Any other suggestion that I can look for.

Comment: Whenever you create new profile, it has by default assigned with workflow.. and if it is in draft stat then will not get published and result will not reflect. I have created same scenario and it is working perfectly fine for me. Please remove other condition from component if any and try to change source instead of hide. Some times if any other condition satisfy first then it will not check the rest of the conditions.

Comment: I will check the workflow thing and then will confirm it

Comment: I faced the same problem, by default all new profile is in Draft state of workflow, please check the workflow, change the state then publish it.. it will work