# Personalization not working (Pattern Card & profile Card)

Tags: xdb, sitecore-client, personalization

Using `Sitecore .NET 8.1 (rev. 151003)`.

Created `ABC pattern card` & assign specific placeholder of page.

**Used rule:** 
  where the current contact matches the ABC pattern card in the ABCD profile.

when a user reaches a specific pattern value, placeholder content should be changed.

Content available in the interaction table of `MongoDB`

I have tried multiple time but it's not working.  Please, can you guide me on the same.

Thanks

Comment: You can refer this might help to solve your issue. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10258/component-not-updating-according-to-pattern-card